# Python 3.6 returning a result different than expected

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the string

> Triax PFG Interface Boards: Inova: P/N 01-903510-02 and Unity plus:
>   P/N 01-903510-03\r\n\r\nService

from the following:

> \r\n\r\nSupersedes\r\nNone\r\n\r\nTriax PFG Interface Boards: Inova:
>   P/N 01-903510-02 and Unity plus: P/N 01-903510-03\r\n\r\nService
>   Serial Numbers:\r\nUS00000000-US99999999\r\n\r\n

using the regex:

```
Supersedes:?[\\r\\n ]+[\w\-\s]+[\\r\\n ]+(.*)[\\r\\n ]+Serial Numbers?:?[ \\r\\n]+.*?
```

This works as expected when I try it out on regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/eHdhBV/1/

But when I try this in Python 3.6, the first matched group is not what I'm expecting:

```
import re
result = re.search('Supersedes:?[\\r\\n ]+[\w\-\s]+[\\r\\n ]+(.*)[\\r\\n ]+Serial Numbers?:?[ \\r\\n]+.*?', '\r\n\r\nSupersedes\r\nNone\r\n\r\nTriax PFG Interface Boards: Inova: P/N 01-903510-02 and Unity plus: P/N 01-903510-03\r\n\r\nService Serial Numbers:\r\nUS00000000-US99999999\r\n\r\n', re.S|re.M)
result[1]
'Boards: Inova: P/N 01-903510-02 and Unity plus: P/N 01-903510-03\r\n\r\nService'
```

Why does Python leave out 'Triax PFG Interface'?

Edit:

As suggested, I tried this with a string literal as well.  Here are the results:

```
rx = r'Supersedes:?[\\r\\n ]+[\w\-\s]+[\\r\\n ]+(.*)[\\r\\n ]+Serial Numbers?:?[ \\r\\n]+.*?'
result = re.search(rx, '\r\n\r\nSupersedes\r\nNone\r\n\r\nTriax PFG Interface Boards: Inova: P/N 01-903510-02 and Unity plus: P/N 01-903510-03\r\n\r\nService Serial Numbers:\r\nUS00000000-US99999999\r\n\r\n', re.S|re.M)
result[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You are testing against a string literal at the online tester while you should test against the literal string. Try [`r'Supersedes:?\s+[\w -]+\s+(.*)\s+Serial Numbers?:?\s+.*'`](https://regex101.com/r/0iIKG2/1), or [`r'Supersedes:?\s+[\w -]+\s+(.*)\sSerial Number'`](https://regex101.com/r/0iIKG2/2). Perhaps, the regex can be enhanced further, but please share the exact requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I tried it using a string literal and the regex didn't find any matches.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Why do you double backslashes in a raw string literal? Don't do that. Use `re.findall(r'Supersedes:?\s+[\w -]+\s+(.*)\sSerial Number', s, re.S)`. Or `re.search(r'Supersedes:?\s+[\w -]+\s+(.*)\sSerial Number', s, re.S)`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/paNNCB).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Oh, I see what you mean.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing against a string literal at the online tester while you should test against the literal string.

The

```
'\r\n\r\nSupersedes\r\nNone\r\n\r\nTriax PFG Interface Boards: Inova: P/N 01-903510-02 and Unity plus: P/N 01-903510-03\r\n\r\nService Serial Numbers:\r\nUS00000000-US99999999\r\n\r\n'
```

is a string literal, the `\r` and `\n` inside it are *escape sequences* that are changed by Python string engine to CR and LF symbols respectively.

The string literal represents the following *literal string*:

```
Supersedes
None

Triax PFG Interface Boards: Inova: P/N 01-903510-02 and Unity plus: P/N 01-903510-03

Service Serial Numbers:
US00000000-US99999999
```

with 2 empty lines at the start and end. See [the actual regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/WGGvuU/2).

You may use

```
import re
s = '\r\n\r\nSupersedes\r\nNone\r\n\r\nTriax PFG Interface Boards: Inova: P/N 01-903510-02 and Unity plus: P/N 01-903510-03\r\n\r\nService Serial Numbers:\r\nUS00000000-US99999999\r\n\r\n'
m = re.search(r'Supersedes:?\s+[\w -]+\s+(.*)\sSerial Number', s, re.S)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/paNNCB)

**Details**

- `Supersedes:?` - `Supersedes:` or `Supersedes` substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (including vertical ones, i.e. line breaks)
- `[\w -]+` - 1+ word, space and/or hyphen chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - any 0+ chars (including line breaks, too, due to `re.S` flag) as many as possible (replace `*` with `*?` to make it match as few chars as possible if there are more than 1 match expected)
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `Serial Number` - a `Serial Number` substring.