# Python 3.6 Regex Producing Unexpected Results (despite using string literals)

Tags: python, regex

A short time ago I had [an almost identical problem to this one and it was fixed by using string literals instead of literal strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397205/python-3-6-returning-a-result-different-than-expected/51397548#51397548).  This time, I took care to use string literals but it didn't fix the problem.

I am trying to extract a section from a string and the results I get from Python are different than what regex101 shows I should be getting.  I'm using this

```
Supersedes:?[\\r\\n ]+(?:[A-Za-z\-0-9])*[\\w\-\\s]+[\\r\n ]+(.*)[\\r\\n ]+Serial Numbers:?
```

to match this text:

> \r\n\r\nSupersedes\r\nNone\r\n\r\nChanges to VGA-77 gas module
>   assembly (0110444290)\r\n\r\nService Serial
>   Numbers:\r\nUS00000000-US99999999\r\n\r

I'm expecting the first captured group to give me

```
n\r\nChanges to VGA-77 gas module assembly (0110444290)\r\n\r\nService
```

https://regex101.com/r/eHdhBV/2

But when I try this in Python:

```
rx = r'Supersedes:?[\r\n ]+(?:[A-Za-z\-0-9])*[\w\-\s]+[\r\n ]+(.*)[\r\n ]+Serial Numbers:?'
string = '\r\n\r\nSupersedes\r\nNone\r\n\r\nChanges to VGA-77 gas module assembly (0110444290)\r\n\r\nService Serial Numbers:\r\nUS00000000-US99999999\r\n\r'
result = re.search(rx, string, re.M|re.S)
result[1]
'(0110444290)\r\n\r\nService'
```

The result is not the same as what is shown on regex101.  What's causing this?

Comment: Why are you doing that again? Here is your [actual string in the tester](https://regex101.com/r/eHdhBV/3).

Comment: Try [`r'Supersedes:?\s*[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+(.*?)[ \r\n]+Serial Numbers'`](https://regex101.com/r/eHdhBV/5)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  What do you mean, actual string?  I didn't alter the string after saving the link.  The actual string is on the link I posted.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I can see how that's a better regex, but that doesn't explain why python and regex101 are giving different results

Comment: See my previous answer, I added more details, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51397548/3832970. You are confusing *string literals* and *literal strings*. Before you understand that difference, you need to stop programming since it is the basics. First, read about string literals, there are a lot of tutorials and docs online.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the current issue, you may use

```
m = re.search(r'Supersedes:?\s*[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+(.*?)[ \r\n]+Serial Numbers', s, re.S)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/eHdhBV/5).

Please note that you should use *literal strings* in online regex testers, that is, convert your `\n` and `\r` into line breaks.

**Pattern details**

- `Supersedes:?` - `Supersedes:` or `Supersedes`
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces
- `[^\r\n]*` - any 0+ chars other than LF an CR
- `[\r\n]+` - 1+ LR or CR symbols
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `[ \r\n]+` - 1+ spaces, CR or LF
- `Serial Numbers` - a literal `Serial Numbers` string.